# PHP Form Select Array Increments by Value Threshold?

Tags: php

I was able to opt to out of a hard coded select of form values from 50,000 to 75,000,000 in increments of 100000.

```
<select name="<?php echo $search_parameter; ?>" id="<?php echo $search_parameter; ?>" class="form-control">
<option value=""><?php echo __( $search_labels[$i], 'tt' ); ?></option>
<?php for( $j = 50000; $j <= 75000000; $j += 50000 ) : ?>
<option value="<?php echo $j; ?>"><?php echo number_format( $j ); ?></option>
<?php endfor; ?>
</select>
```

This saved alot of time.  I'd like to further customize this but really have no where to start outside of hard-coding this which seems like a step backwards?

How would I have PHP automate different incrementals based on value of $j thresholds? Is this even possible or am I asking too much?

- 50000 - 500000 - 50k increments
- 500001 - 1000000 - 100k increments
- 1000001 - 5000000 - 500k increments
- 5000001 - 10000000 - 1 million increments
- 10m+     10 million increments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simple approach, that nevertheless should fit for you:

```
<?php 
$inc = 50000;
for( $j = 50000; $j <= 75000000; $j += $inc) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $j; ?>"><?php echo number_format( $j ); ?></option>
    <?php 
    if ($j>10000000) {$inc=10000000;}
    elseif ($j>5000000) {$inc=1000000;}
    elseif //and so on...
endfor; ?>
```

Note that we're comparing "from the top", so that only a small number of comparisons/assignments should be needed.

Another possibility would be to define the thresholds and increments in an additional array and evaluate them in each loop.

Edit: Added two missing `;`s.

Comment: I'm getting a Syntax error on the if/elseif but I can't figure out why?

<select name="<?php echo $search_parameter; ?>" id="<?php echo $search_parameter; ?>" class="form-control">
<option value=""><?php echo __( $search_labels[$i], 'tt' ); ?></option>
<?php 
$inc = 50000;
for( $j = 50000; $j <= 75000000; $j += $inc) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $j; ?>"><?php echo number_format( $j ); ?></option>
    <?php 
    if ($j>10000000) {$inc=10000000}
    elseif ($j>5000000) {$inc=1000000}
endfor; ?>

</select>

Comment: Sorry, my bad. There were the `;`s missing in the curly brackets of the if statements. Corrected my answer.